# memory leak issues after upgrading ember cli from 3.4.3. to 3.24.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

We are facing an issue on JS heap size grows substantially over time, indicating a memory leak after ember upgrade to 3.24.0, DOM nodes also increase seemingly without bound.

Over time, our test cases are failing due to shortage of node memory and few apps are working after setting the node --max-old-space-size=8192 whereas few apps are not working after increasing node space

Environment
•   Ember 3.24.0 (upgraded version )
•   Node.js/npm: node 12.22.1, npm 6.14.12
•   Browser: Chrome
We are seeking the help to find the right direction to fix the issue

Note:
Due to security concerns, we cant share more info/code snippet/part of our code here.

Thanks,

Comment: sharing more info will help the community to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.